# Is a printer profiling question appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been away for a while due to life getting in the way, but have recently been wrestling with getting some half decent prints from my old epson inkjet. I wanted to post what I had found but as it was edging towards software usage I posted as an answer to an old question on askubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1318472/653727). Is it worth copying the question across?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printer profiling questions in the context of photographic workflow are appropriate, but answering your question, "Is it worth copying the question across?"... generally, **no**. Cross-posting is heavily discouraged amongst Stack Exchange sites. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/175991) to the Meta-SE question, [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/175991)

Comment: Thanks. I've never rrally thought of stack exchange as a unified site. Looks like a bit of a can of worms that has been elevated to an almost philosophical level! It seems to leave the door adjar to a signpost question "how do I profile my printer for better photo prints?" answer "on ubuntu linux I have done this [link to ask ubuntu]". Any thoughts?

Comment: Or even an answer on this -[https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer] though I know that link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @dmkonlinux I wouldn't quite say the Stacks are a unified site. More like a loose confederation of siloed subjects all holding similar rules of posting.

Comment: I went ahead and added a more general answer with a link to the [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/122803/60903) by @jrista, which is a great piece of work by the way. If this doesn't work for the site let me know and it's gone.

Comment: @dmkonlinux no, it's great to link to the answer on Ask Ubuntu. Nice answer.